# Error: Cannot read property 'None' of undefined stack

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

Using react native and then suddenly received the following error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'None' of undefined
 stack: 
  <unknown>  index.ios.bundle:24759
  require    index.ios.bundle:254
  <unknown>  index.ios.bundle:23809
  require    index.ios.bundle:254
  <unknown>  index.ios.bundle:1508
  require    index.ios.bundle:254
  <unknown>  index.ios.bundle:1435
  require    index.ios.bundle:254
  require    index.ios.bundle:200
  <unknown>  index.ios.bundle:59178
 URL: undefined
 line: undefined
 message: Cannot read property 'None' of undefinedhandleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:69handleErrorWithRedBox @ InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:38ErrorUtils.reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:28require @ require.js:197(anonymous function) @ RunMainModule.js:1
```

I'm not sure what the problem is as I have not changed anything to my code and the error doesn't reference any of the lines that I have written. I'm just learning react so my apologies for any novice questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I use a npm package called react-native-looped-carousel, I got same error, after I remove it, it works fine again.

You may try remove some recently installed package, that may cause this error I think.